# Groovy not returning a list of lists after for loop

Tags: variables, for-loop, groovy

I am learning Groovy and I am trying to return a list of lists but when I do my for loop in `counter()` function, it automatically returns just giving me the first iteration and doesn't continue with the rest of the words.

I found the issue is in the for loop of `counter()`, it looks like Groovy shares the `i` variable in the loops. Coming from Python each for loop holds its own variable `i`. Is there something like this in Groovy?

```
lista = ["apple","banana","orange","melon","watermelon"]

def copaa(a_list_of_things){
    lista_to_return = []
    for (i = 0; i < a_list_of_things.size(); i++) {
        lis = counter(a_list_of_things[i])
        lista_to_return.add(lis)
    }
    return lista_to_return
}

def counter(word){
    list_of_times = []
    //return "bla"
    for (i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        list_of_times.add(i)
    }
    return list_of_times
}

ls = copaa(lista)
println(ls)
```

Comment: Can you please gives some feedback? If the answer doesn't solve your problem, can you provide some failing test cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Avoid global scope**:
prefix the `i` variable declarations with the implicit type `def` (actually `Object`) or an appropriate explicit type (e.g. `int` or `Integer`) to make the scope local to the loop. Otherwise these variables are placed (as a single one `i`) in the bindings of the script  (practically it's treated as a global variable).

Modify the relevant lines of your code like this:

```
// with def...
for (def i = 0; i < a_list_of_things.size(); i++) {
// ...
for (def i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {

// ...OR with an explicit type (e.g. int) the scope is limited 
// to the for loop as expected
for (int i = 0; i < a_list_of_things.size(); i++) {
// ...
for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
```

**Output**

> [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]

---

**The Groovy Way**

To gives you some extra hints I reimplemented your algorithm using some of the cool features `groovy` provides ([collect](http://mrhaki.blogspot.it/2010/05/groovy-goodness-use-collect-with.html), [closure](http://www.groovy-lang.org/closures.html), [numeric ranges](http://mrhaki.blogspot.it/2009/09/groovy-goodness-keep-your-values-in.html)):

```
wordList = ["apple","watermelon"]

// collect process each word (the implicit variable it) and returns a new list
// each field of the new list is a range from 0 till it.size() (not included)
outList = wordList.collect { (0 ..< it.size()).toArray() }

assert outList == [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: The **"Groovy Way"** would be to use `collect` instead of mutating a list in the `each` block